# Bluemix user-created container - 'This page can’t be displayed'

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

Problem:  'This page can’t be displayed' when I select a user-defined container from Bluemix catalog.
 https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/?category=containers&taxonomyNavigation=containers&env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

Background: The build successfully completed and the image was created

```
cf ic build -t tomcat-mine .
cf ic images |grep tomcat-mine
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ztechsec/tomcat-mine latest 7cd1e6870ffd 55 minutes ago      142 MB
```

The container that was created in the previous step shows up under Bluemix Catalog > Containers.

When selecting the container that was created (tomcat-mine), the URL generates the 'This page can’t be displayed.' This URL generates the 'This page can’t be displayed' from the Bluemix -> Catalog > Containers:

https://catalog/images/tomcat-mine?org=28bfa082-2a8e-43cf-963d-7b7b28455603&space=085c044d-55cf-497a-8219-d6b668d63668&org_region=us-south&is_org_manager=false&ims_account=1177915&env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

Questions:

1. What would cause this issue?
2. What are possible workarounds?

Comment: Accessing the user created container works using chrome browser. The workaround is to use chrome browser instead of IE

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to inspect the image with the CLI?

cf ic inspect 7cd1e6870ffd - does that work for you?

Comment: Yes. The cf ic inspect works fine.  The Bluemix console works fine using chrome and the cf ic commands work. The issue appears to be using the Bluemix console using IE.  I'll just use chrome for now and close out the issue. Thanks for your assistance.